# Automatic id assign

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

i'm a student and im having problems using the automatic increment because when i delete a row it will continue to increment. explaining:

i want to increment id automaticly
so:

```
  id   name      age

  1    michael   18

  2    katy      17

  3    jack      20
```

now i delete row 3 and when i click in the button new it'll go to the id 4 instead of id 3
i'v tried rows.count and refresh the textbox but nothing

some adicional info

```
ds= dataset
maxrows = ds.Tables("virtualtable").Rows.Count

idcliTextBox.Text = maxrows
```

how do i make it set id to the real last row?

Comment: That's what "auto-increment" means.  It is not a problem.  Don't make it one, reliably picking the next available number from a table with thousands of rows is *very* expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the correct behavior and it is not a problem. Usually the autoincrement columns in a database are never reset to accomodate for empty holes caused by deletion of previous inserted records.
The autoincrement column is usually used as primary key to uniquely identify a single record in your table.

Suppose that your table represents `students` where the `ID` field value is used as foreign key for another table `examresults`. In this table you store the exam result of your students.  Your student Katy (2) has two records in the examresults table for the graduation in math and geography.

If you delete the record with ID=2 from the table `students` and the related records from `examresults` changing the record for Jack from 3 to 2 means that you need to change also the related records for examresults of Jack. This is very impractical and useless if you think about it.